# Rename selected Kendo PanelBar

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-panelbar, panelbar

How would you rename the currently selected PanelBar.
I have a select function that works, this method removes the selected panelBar

```
panelbar.remove(panelbar.select());
```

This method renames the first PanelBar

```
panelbar.wrapper.find(".k-header:first").text("foo")
```

Tried with no joy

```
panelbar.wrapper.find(panelbar.select().text("New Text"));
panelbar.wrapper.find(panelbar.select()(".k-header").text("New Text"));
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within your fuction

```
panelbar.select().find("> .k-link").text("New Text");
```

Here's a Dojo http://dojo.telerik.com/EDekO/2

You could do it using the select event e.g.

```
 @(Html.Kendo().PanelBar()
.Name("panelbar")
.Events(events => events.Select("onSelect"))
```

Then your onSelect function

```
function onSelect(e) {
   $(e.item).find("> .k-link").text("New Text");
}
```